# Chaining redux thunks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I want to update user details hit submit, wait for the updating and then post this to firebase.

I have the following:

```
export const writeToFirebase = details => {
  return firebase
    .database()
    .ref("/")
    .set({
      id: details.id,
      name: details.name,
      username: details.username,
      email: details.email
    });
};

export const updateUserDetails = updatedUser => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: UPDATE_USER_DETAILS, updatedUser });
  };
};

export const updateUserDetailsThenUpdateFirebase = updatedUser => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return dispatch(updateUserDetails(updatedUser)).then(() => {
      const storeData = getState();
    });
  };
};
```

the last function is the one I will be calling on click. The middle function is gonna take the input and then update the store (this currently works correctly)

however, I'm getting it cant read `then` of undefined? I tried following this: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1676

I must be really close, I just need to return a promise correctly. 
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing `writeToFirebase` call, and calling `then` from the wrong place, try this code instead:

```
export const updateUserDetailsThenUpdateFirebase = updatedUser => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(updateUserDetails(updatedUser));

    writeToFirebase(updatedUser).then(() => {
      const storeData = getState();
      // ... called after firebase finishes
    });
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

ah, so I was very close:
amazingly, and amagically,

this works:

```
export const updateUserDetailsThenUpdateFirebase = updatedUser => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return dispatch(updateUserDetails(updatedUser)).then(() => {
      const foundUser = getState().selectedUser;
      const userToUpdate = getState().users.users.filter(
        user => user.id === foundUser.id
      );
      return writeToFirebase(userToUpdate, 1);
    });
  };
};
```